# Angular 2 - Remove non essential files from QuickStart seed

Tags: macos, angular, unix

Following the setup guide [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html) and trying to delete non-essentials files from QuickStart seed. It says to run the following commands on Mac:

```
xargs -a non-essential-files.txt rm -rf
rm app/*.spec*.ts
rm non-essential-files.txt
```

The first command doesn't work. Looks like `xargs` on Mac doesn't have `-a` option.

What is the equivalent to the first command on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing a `-a` option as well, that's strange.

Just copy & paste this (it's just a concat list of all those files) to remove everything:

```
rm -rf .git .gitignore .travis.yml *.spec*.ts CHANGELOG.md e2e favicon.ico karma.conf.js karma-test-shim.js LICENSE non-essential-files.txt protractor.config.js README.md app/*.spec*.ts non-essential-files.txt
```

Comment: Yeah, Linux `xargs` has `-a` option, but OSX `xargs` doesn't. Thanks for providing the command, but actually I want to know how to delete a list of files from a text list.

Answer (score 0):

```
xargs rm -rf < non-essential-files.txt
```

Should work.